# Retornar valores através de uma classe derivada do mesmo parent

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, herança

Tenho as classes 1, 2a e 2b, sendo que 1 é a classe principal, enquanto 2a e 2b estende a classe 1. É possível através da classe 2a acessar valores da classe 2b diretamente ou através da classe pai?

Exemplo básico:

```
class system{
}

class modulos extends system{

    function __construct(){
        $exemple = controllers::exemple();
    }
}

class controllers extends system{

    public function exemple(){
        return true;
    }
}

$system = new system();
```

Comment: Esses valores são `public`, `protected` ou `private`?

Comment: Pode colocar o código das classes?

Answer (score 1):

Dessa maneira que você fez é impossível. Quando `modulos` e `controllers` herdam de `system` cada classe segue um caminho diferente e as duas não se relacionam.

Se existe um método em comum que vai ser usado por todas as classes que herdam de `system`, então pela lógica quem deve conter esse método é `system`.

```
class system{
    protected function exemple() {
        return true;
    }
}

class modulos extends system{

    function __construct(){
        $exemple = this->exemple();
    }
}

class controllers extends system{}

$system = new system();
```

Existem outras maneiras de solucionar isso, mas todas incluindo a que eu dei acima vão depender de como você quer que seja a relação entre suas classes.

Answer (score 0):

Olá!

Como a classe 2b(controllers) é uma **dependência** da classe 2a(modulos), creio que o construtor de 2a deveria receber *obrigatóriamente* uma referência de 2b.

Eu faria desta forma:

```
class modulos extends system{

  function __construct($controllers){
      $exemple = $controllers::exemple();
  }
}
```